# How to configure Background App Refresh using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, appdelegate, completionhandler

I have following function to download JSON data in my SeachVC (UIViewController) which works perfect.

```
func downloadJSON(){

    guard let url = URL(string: "myURL") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let downloadedCurrencies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Currency].self, from: data)

            // Adding downloaded data into Local Array
            Currencies = downloadedCurrencies

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Here! Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

To implement Background App Refresh, I added following functions into App Delegate;

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Background App Refresh Config
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let VC = window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC {
        // Update JSON data
        VC.downloadJSON()
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

However, when I simulate Background App Refresh on the simulator, I get warning:

Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Where I am going to implement completion handler and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to move your downloading code from the view controller and into another class or at least modify you current background refresh method to instantiate the view controller if required.  Background refresh can be triggered when your app hasn't been launched in the foreground, so the `if let` will fall through.

Consider the code in your question:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let VC = window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC {
        // Update JSON data
        VC.downloadJSON()
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

If the `if let...` doesn't pass then you exit from the function without calling the `completionHandler`, so you get the *runtime* warning that the completion handler was not called.

You could modify your code to include a call to the `completionHandler` in an `else` case, but in this case no fetch will have taken place:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let VC = window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC {
        // Update JSON data
        VC.downloadJSON()
        completionHandler(.newData)
    } else {
        completionHandler(.noData)
}
```

Or you could instantiate the view controller (or I would suggest another data fetching class) if required:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let vc = (window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC) ?? SearchVC()
        // Update JSON data
    vc.downloadJSON()
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

You should also modify your `downloadJSON` function to include a completion handler argument, which you invoke when the JSON download is complete.  This will let you call the background fetch completion handler once you have actually downloaded the data:

```
func downloadJSON(completion: ((Bool,Error?) -> Void )? = nil)) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "myURL") else { 
        completion?(false, nil)
        return 
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard nil == err else {
            completion?(false, err)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { 
            completion?(false, nil)
            return 
        }

        do {
            let downloadedCurrencies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Currency].self, from: data)

            // Adding downloaded data into Local Array
            Currencies = downloadedCurrencies
            completion(true,nil)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Here! Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            completion?(false,jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let vc = (window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC) ?? SearchVC()
        // Update JSON data
    vc.downloadJSON() { (newData,error) in
        if let err = error {
           NSLog("Background fetch error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
           completionHandler(.fail)
        } else {
            completionHandler(newData ? .newData:.noData)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update September 2019**

Note that iOS 13 introduces new background fetch and processing functionality. Refer to this [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I am newbie so please excuse my questions. How can I add completionHandler into my downloadJSON? Oh you added that too. Thank you so much! Going to implement your input! Really appreciated!

Comment: last partial code gives an error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on "{" at the vc.downloadJSON() { (error) in

Comment: That is because you need to add a completion handler argument to your download function - see my edited answer

Comment: Works perfect. No errors. I wish I can mark your question as answer as well. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: The `completionHandler` is provided by the system when it calls the delegate method. It is your responsibility to call it with the result of your fetch once it is complete. `.newData` indicates that new data was fetched. iOS uses the result to identify how often and when your app should be given an opportunity to perform a background fetch.

Comment: This is work upto iOS 11 but i need iOS 9 +. how can i used this with old iOS

Comment: What part doesn't work on iOS9? `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` was introduced in iOS 7.  (and really, iOS9?)

Answer (score 3):

It's propably because you don't call the `completionHandler` at the else-case (which will never happen but the compiler doesn't know)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let VC = window?.rootViewController as? SearchVC {
        // Update JSON data
        VC.downloadJSON()
        completionHandler(.newData)
    } else {
        completionHandler(.failed)
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, this is a run-time warning issued by iOS, not the compiler, because *it did happen*; the `if` test failed because the view controller wasn't available in the background.  Adding a call to the completion handler in the `else` will cause the warning to go away since the completion handler was called, but no download has occurred.